# Does Coriolis force effect a particle that has only a tangential velocity in a rotating frame?

Tags: reference-frames, coriolis-effect

Imagine a disc rotating at an angular velocity $\omega$, a particle on the disc which is attached to the disc so its also rotating at an angular velocity $\omega$.

1. Now the particle has tangential velocity and no radial velocity. Will the particle have a Coriolis effect?
2. In general will a an object which just has tangential velocity have Coriolis effect?

Please give me some kind of proof to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Coriolis acceleration is $2\vec{v}\times\vec{\omega}$, where the velocity vector $\vec{v}$ is measured in the rotating reference frame. In your example, if I'm reading you right, the particle is moving with the disc, so $\vec{v}=0$, so the Coriolis acceleration is zero. In general, if you have either a radial or tangential velocity component in the rotating frame, the Coriolis acceleration will be nonzero, but velocity components in the axial direction don't count.

Because of this, an airplane flying east over the equator needs very, very slightly less lift than an airplane flying west. The effect is very small unless it's moving very fast, though.